# How to list the scopes granted to a specific application

Tags: github, github-api, github-oauth

A React application has a standard OAuth flow that grants access to Github with no scope.  The user can go through another OAuth flow to grant `repo` access to the application.  How can the application tell if the user has granted the `repo` scope or not?

This looks like it would be doable using the `/application/grants` API, but that API is scheduled to be deprecated and it only accepts Basic Auth.  What's the replacement?

Comment: As per the deprecation notice [here](https://developer.github.com/changes/2020-02-14-deprecating-oauth-auth-endpoint/#changes-to-make) , they suggest using a [web application flow](https://developer.github.com/apps/building-oauth-apps/authorizing-oauth-apps/#web-application-flow). I haven't tried it, though.

Comment: @AsifKamranMalick Thanks for the comment.  I looked through that flow and I can't figure out how I would know to go through the flow with a user?  I have the flow built and it works but I don't want to request the flow every time when it's not necessary?